# Moving file based on extension from old to new folder, and then adding prefix to the file in new folder based on previous folder name

Tags: bash

I have two files in folder A and would like to move one of the files, if it is text file, to a new folder. The folder structure and content are such that

Folder A has two files, that is book.txt  and book.csv, inside it.

I want to move only the txt file to a new folder called Folder B. At the end, I hope to see the following folder structures and contents.

Folder A
|
|___book.csv

Folder B
|
|___Folder A_book.txt

The code that I am capable to use is as followed, but it did not work.

```
for file in *; find . -name '*.txt'; -exec mv '$file'.{} ./Folder\ B;
```

Please advise me.

Comment: "*and then adding prefix to the file in new folder based on previous folder name*" ?! I don't see this reflected in your question text

Comment: @pLumo, I have made the question clearer than before. Can you please advise me because my code is not working? I would like to make it clear that This is not a homework question.

Comment: I would advise you use [shellcheck.net](https://shellcheck.net) to fix obvious syntax errors. And then think about what you're doing there and what you need to do. What is `for file in * ; ...` doing and what is `find ...`. Why `;` after `'*.txt'` ? What is `-exec mv '$file'.{} ...` ? For such an easy task, there are so many errors in your short code example that I don't know how to help without writing it myself. And this is not the purpose of this site, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a one liner:

```
for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" ../Folder\ B/"${PWD##*/}"_"$f"; done
```

or the multi line equivalent:

```
for f in *.txt
    do 
    mv "$f" ../Folder\ B/"${PWD##*/}"_"$f"
    done
```

Asuming `Folder A` and `Folder B` are in the same level, run the above code ( **either one** ) from within **Folder A**.

Comment: a bit easier to read `"../Folder B/${PWD##*/}_$f"`

Comment: @bac0n "Ja" :) / Yes that is correct. Moving the quotes around the directory name will eliminate the need to escape the space. I ,however, kept that intact from the OP... maybe this way it is easier for OP to understand and change the directory name since they appear to know how to escape space in directory name.